# How does Spotlight determine which category a file belongs to?

Tags: macos, spotlight, preferences

In Spotlight you can enable and disable file categories that will appear in search results.  [image]
How does Spotlight determine that a certain file belongs to a certain category?
The following specific event triggered this curiosity:

For some time `.tex` files would come up under the Documents category. Spotlight would handle the search `filename.tex` just fine. Then suddenly I could not find `.tex` files anymore in Spotlight. Finder searches were OK though. 
Turns out that I had the Developer category disabled in the Spotlight preferences, and Spotlight now thought that `.tex` files belonged in that category. After enabling the Developer category everything went back to normal.

What made Spotlight decide to switch categories for the `.tex` files?

Comment: I am thinking any other stuff that cannot be categorized to one of these category will be categorized as `Documents`.

Comment: But why has the `.tex` file been categorised under Documents and then under Developer?

Comment: When you right click on one of the .tex files and choose "Open With...", what shows up as the default choice?

Comment: It's also categorized by **I guess** application associations.

Comment: Open with says TexShop, but now `.tex` files also show as Documents again in Spotlight... weird.

Comment: Did you check that file attributes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the parent UTIs defined in an application's Info.plist or in `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist`. `.tex` is not included in the CoreTypes Info.plist, so the UTI depends on which application's UTI declaration was registered first. For example on my installation the UTI was `com.barebones.bbedit.tex-source` and the first parent UTI was `public.source-code`:

```
$ touch a.tex; mdls -n kMDItemContentTypeTree a.tex
kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "com.barebones.bbedit.tex-source",
    "public.source-code",
    "public.plain-text",
    "public.text",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
```

When I deleted BBEdit and rebuilt the Launch Services database, the UTI became `org.tug.tex` and the first parent UTI became `public.text`:

```
$ touch b.tex; mdls -n kMDItemContentTypeTree b.tex
kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "org.tug.tex",
    "public.text",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content",
    "public.plain-text"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with one of my TeX documents, that developed immediately after TeXShop updated itself while I had the document open.

I tried the UTI listing trick above, and it turns out all my other TeX documents are categorised as either "org.tug.tex" or "edu.uo.texshop.tex".  These all come up as 'Documents' in Spotlight searches.  However, the one file that was open while TeXShop updated has now been categorised as "com.barebones.bbedit.tex-source" which seems to fall into the 'Developer' category.

Perhaps the moral of the story in my case is: close all TeXShop documents before allowing the application to update itself.