# Change JSON and CSS files to developer kind in All My Files

Tags: finder, file

In **All My Files**, CSS and JSON files appear in the **Documents** section, even though I would call them developer files. Is there any way I can change their *kind*, so that they appear as **Developer** files?

Comment: I think it depends on which application's UTI declarations were registered first. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/97718.